# Getting null output when using npm package linkedin-scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, linkedin-api

After installation of npm linkedin-scraper package, I created a .js code but I am getting null output with the provided url. How to use the this package properly?

```
var linkedinScraper = require('linkedin-scraper');
var url = 'https://in.linkedin.com/in/[user]';

linkedinScraper(url, function(err, profile) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(profile);
    }
});
```

This is the output I get:

```
output:
{ past: [],
  websites: [],
  experience: [],
  honors: [],
  projects: [],
  educationlist: [],
  name: '',
  headline: '',
  location: '',
  current: '',
  education: '' }
```